# How to prefill a message when the message was user generated?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am working on an app where users can write a blob of text then share it to Facebook.

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill, this is an acceptable use:

> ✔ Populate the user message parameter with content a user manually
>   entered earlier in your app's flow.

If I was manually forming the HTTP request, I can pass the user's message in the `message` URL parameter. However, I would like the FBSDKShareDialog (or similar) to prefill the text input box with this content. This gives me the benefit of not requesting `publish_actions` permission.

Is this possible, or do I have to resort to making a POST?

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK not possible via dialogs, you’ll have to ask for the permission and then post via API call.

Comment: You can't. If you're already popping up the share dialog, then you should just expect that the user will type in the message there, rather than opening another dialog for the message before the share.

Comment: Thanks everyone! @MingLi: It's unfortunate to lose the niceties of the dialog (familiar format for the user, handling permissions, privacy settings, etc). Additionally, even though the user would see a default message from my app, they may want to manipulate it for the audience.

Comment: Are you presenting a default message for the user to alter, or allowing the user to type in a message from a blank dialog? The former, I'm almost certain would violate policy, whereas the latter would be the functional equivalent of just using the share dialog.

Comment: The user creates the content through the app, not just in a single dialog. I'm just suggesting it would be better for the user to have a chance to edit it before it's posted to their feed. The policy should be focused on getting rid of spam-laden/blind posts made by irresponsible developers. It should allow a user to share something they've created with their Facebook friends. But in both cases, if you show the user what they're about to post, they have a chance to decide what violates their wishes. I'll have to wait for review time to see what they think. Stay tuned!

Answer (score 0):

`publish_actions` is deprecated, there is no way to prefill the message anymore - even if it was entered manually.